# PHP isn't inserting into database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having an issue with my PHP script I'm trying to run. The user is supposed to fill out the application with the desired information, and once submitted, goes directly into the database, and displayed on an external, application manager I made. Well.. in submitting the applications, nothing gets added into the database. I've made sure my SQL query is the correct structure as the schema of my database, and still nothing. running the query into the database itself using PHPMyAdmin, and it works just fine..
Here is my full PHP which adds the info from the  into the database.

```
<?php

                $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT username FROM tmod WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'");
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    if (empty($_POST['real']) || empty($_POST['age']) || empty($_POST['why']) || empty($_POST['dif']) || empty($_POST['agree']))
                    {
                        echo '<div class="animated shake">
                                <div class="message error">Please fill in all fields.</div>
                            </div>'; 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) < 1){
                        $q =  mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO `tmod` (AppID,username,realname,age,position,why,different,additional,agree) VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."', '".filter($_POST["real"])."', '".filter($_POST["position"])."',  '".filter($_POST["age"])."', '".filter($_POST["why"])."', '".filter($_POST["dif"])."', '".filter($_POST["additional"])."', '".filter($_POST["agree"])."')");

                        if( $q !== false ) { 
                        echo '<div class="animated shake">
                                <div class="message success"><b>Thank you!</b> Your application has been submitted and is awaiting to be reviewed by staff!</div>
                            </div>'; 
                        } else {
                            echo '<div class="animated shake">
                                <div class="message error">Your application did not go through due to an error.</div>
                            </div>';
                        }
                    }else{
                        echo '<div class="animated shake">
                                <div class="message error">You have already applied, please wait for a reply.</div>
                            </div>';
                        } 
                    }   
                }
            ?>

            <div class="box">
                <div class="contentHeader headerGreen">
                    <div class="inside">
                        Staff Application
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="inside">
                    <form method="post">
                        <div class="form-section">
                            <strong>Username:</strong><br />
                            <input disabled="disabled" type="text" value="{username}">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-section">
                            <strong>Real Name:</strong><br />
                            <input type="text" name="real" maxlength="28">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-section">
                            <strong>Position:</strong><br />
                            <input type="text" name="position" maxlength="28">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-section">
                            <strong>Age:</strong><br />             
                            <select name="age">
                                <?php for ($i = 13; $i <= 60; $i++) : ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                                <?php endfor; ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-section">

                            <textarea name="why" rows="4" cols="29" placeholder="Why Should We Hire You?"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-section">

                            <textarea name="dif" rows="4" cols="40"placeholder="How are you different from the rest?"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-section">
                            <strong>
                            <textarea name="additional" rows="4" cols="40" placeholder="Additional Information - Leave your Skype here" ></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-section" style="float:bottom">
                            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="agree" >
                            <label>I agree to be active on the Habbsane Hotel.</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-section">
                            <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Apply">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Im importing my database connection info.

```
<?php       require_once ('link/to/my/includes/connection.php'); ?>
```

contents of connection.php:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("DB HOST", "root", "db pass", "DB NAME"); ?>
```

Here is the setup of my tmod table in the database

```
`AppID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`different` varchar(6000) DEFAULT NULL,
`username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`realname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`why` varchar(6000) DEFAULT NULL,
`additional` varchar(6000) DEFAULT NULL,
`agree` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`denied` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Not Read Yet',
`reply` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
`save` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: add some basic error checking and you would find your problem. may want to fix the huge security issues after hat

Comment: mind elaborating any? -_- trying to learn here. you telling me i have problems, doesnt help me any, i already know that.

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Have you checked that `$_POST['submit']` is actually set? Also you should be checking the return value from `mysqli_query($mysqli, $q2);`

Comment: Your SQL statement has a **MASSIVE SECURITY HOLE**, it is open to [SQL Injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/), learn how to use [PDO](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) or [Prepared Statements](https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection) to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: So something like this nick?

Comment: You can add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");` to the top of your file for debugging purposes.  Do not leave in production though.

Comment: call `session_start()` before using `$_SESSION` and don't concatenate session values into SQL, you may be vulnerable to SQLInjection, you should always used Prepared statements because you lose nothing by using them.

Comment: after making changes above ^^^  Mocking the error reporting returns nothing other than a small error, in another file thats linked (nothing to do with this). @Nick after adding that section to see if my $q returns false or not, it is returning false.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can add

```
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

to output mysql errors.  Do not leave in production.

---

Your database is set up with `AppID int(11) NOT NULL`

But your code shows:

```
"INSERT INTO `tmod` (AppID, username,`realname`,age,position,why,different,additional,agree) 
VALUES (NULL,...
```

You are inserting `NULL` into AppID.  Make sure AppID is set to auto increment on the database side.

Additionally, you are inserting a value for the column `position` but missing the `position` column within your table. (Added based on OPs comment for completeness).

Please keep in mind what @Grant said about [SQL Injection](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/) and using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: you can pass null in if it's Auto Increment, just saying.

Comment: Oh my gosh, wow, i didnt even notice thatT-T. originally setting up my database, i was sure that i had it as AI, it had worked before ive done multiple imports and exports, modifications. etc. Thank you! ill change it now, and make sure it works

Comment: What @ArtisticPhoenix said too.

Comment: The AppID column is already set to AI, but its not letting me change it from NOT NULL
full export of my tmod table shows this,
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h9QxW5ajxBKVSaLLwUjoAk/1 (i changed NOT NULL to DEFAULT NULL, still changes it to NOT NULL)

Comment: If you have it set to AI then it will be set as the primary key and won't let you change it to DEFAULT NULL.

Comment: just thought id give it a try. and yeah, took off AI, and was able to change the Default, i realized that. thank you :)

Comment: i just saw that @Mocking. thank you, i think that got my situation fixed. making some changes now. anyone else realize i was missing the position column in my db? EDIT: FIXED!! Thank you so much, i didnt know about the mysql error reporting like that

Comment: Glad you figured it out UnholyAnon.  Please keep in mind what @Grant said in the comments though.

Comment: oh for sure @Mocking i understand the risk especially when your dealing with other peoples information. Im just fixing up something that was given to me, have been kind of looking into PDO, im still getting the hang of mysqli, they said instead of mysql use mysqli, then instead of using mysqli, use PDO. just trying to catch up lol. Thank you for your advice, you too Grant.